# why this FD make a 3NF?

Tags: database-normalization

Question like this:

Consider the relation scheme ABCDEF satisfying the following functional dependencies:

BC --> ADEF

CD --> B

E --> D

BC is a key and designated as primary. Explain why the relation is in 3NF.

It seems not a 3NF to me, because E-->D is a transitive dependency, but the question asked like this it must to be a 3NF ? So how do I explain it's a 3NF?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with MySQL or Oracle, so I removed the tags.

Comment: Maybe you should paste your definition of 3NF into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BC is a key and designated as primary.

This isn't relevant.

What *is* relevant is that there are *three* candidate keys: BC, CD, and CE.

A relation is in 3NF if and only if

- The relation is in 2NF, *and*
- every *non-prime attribute* is non-transitively dependent on *every* candidate key.

A non-prime attribute is an attribute that is not part of *any* candidate key.

- Prime attributes: B, C, D, E.
- Non-prime attributes: A, F.

> E->D is a transitive dependency

No, it's not. Both E and D are prime attributes. A transitive dependency must involve either A or F. The FD E->D *is* a problem, but it's not a problem for 3NF. It's a problem for BCNF.

I'll leave it to you to figure out whether the relation is in 2NF. (That's the *other* prerequisite to this relation being in 3NF.)